# Selecting a subset of columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to print all the columns of a data table `dt` except one of them named `V3` but don't want to refer to it by number but by name. This is the code that I have:

```
  dt = data.table(matrix(sample(c(0,1),5,rep=T),50,10))
  dt[,-3,with=FALSE]   #  Is this the only way to not print column "V3"?
```

Using the `data frame` way, one could do this through the code:

```
  df = data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1),5,rep=T),50,10))
  df[,!(colnames(df)%in% c("X3"))]
```

So, my question is: is there another way to not print one column in a data table without the necessity of refer to it by number? I'd like to find something similar to the data frame syntax I used above but using data table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select subset of columns in data.table R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094645/select-subset-of-columns-in-data-table-r)

Comment: @hhh that's not a correct duplicate; it should be closed the other way around

Comment: @Jaap I know but the quality of the newer question thread is better hence I voted other way around.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use a very similar syntax as for a `data.frame`, but add the argument `with=FALSE`:

```
dt[, setdiff(colnames(dt),"V9"), with=FALSE]
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V10
 1:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 2:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
 3:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
 4:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
 5:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
 6:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
```

---

The use of `with=FALSE` is nicely explained in the documentation for the `j` argument in `?data.table`:

*j: A single column name, single expresson of column names, `list()` of expressions of column names, an expression or function call that evaluates to list (including `data.frame` and `data.table` which are lists, too), or (when `with=FALSE`) same as j in `[.data.frame`.*

---

From *v1.10.2* onwards it is also possible to do this as follows:

```
keep <- setdiff(names(dt), "V9")
dt[, ..keep]
```

Prefixing a symbol with `..` will look up in calling scope (i.e. the Global Environment) and its value taken to be column names or numbers ([source](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1)).

Answer (score 14):

Edit 2019-09-27 with a more modern approach

You can do this with `patterns` as mentioned above; or, you can do it with `!` if there's a vector of names already:

```
dt[ , !'V3']
# or
drop_cols = 'V3'
dt[ , !..drop_cols]
```

`..` means "look up one level"

---

Older version using `with=FALSE` (`data.table` is moving away from this argument steadily)

Here's a way that uses `grep` to convert to numeric and allow negative column indexing:

```
dt[, -grep("^V3$", names(dt)), with=FALSE]
```

You did say "V3" was to be excluded, right?

Comment: What about whit this approach if you want to exclude more than one column? @DWin

Comment: It's very easy to add conditions with regex-grep. Just use the OR symbol "|". `dt[ , -grep("^V3$|^V9$", names(dt), with=FALSE`

Comment: @IRTFM how does it work if you only want to use one element in a vector such as drop_cols(i) in a loop for example?

Comment: @HermanToothrot I'm not certain I understand the question. Perhaps you meant to use a multi-element character vector named `drop_cols` created outside the loop and index with the for-loop iterator? I thought that it might involve using `drop_cols[i]` after the double-dot within the loop, but I was wrong. Deserves another question.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe it's only in recent versions of data.table (I'm using 1.9.6), but you can do:

```
dt[, -'V3']
```

For several columns:

```
dt[, -c('V3', 'V9')]
```

Note that the quotes around the variable names are necessary.
Also, if your column names are stored in a variable, say `cols`, you'll need to do `dt[, -cols, with=FALSE]`.

Answer (score 7):

From version 1.12.0 onwards, it is also possible to select columns using regular expressions on their names:

```
iris_DT <- as.data.table(iris)

iris_DT[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns(".e.al")]
```

Answer (score -1):

To summarize the answer to this question, and also to make it
a) negation-friendly (so that you can also select columns by negation),
b) pipe-line friendly (so that you can use in a pipeline with %>% operator), and
c) so that you can select using both column numbers and column names,
these are available options:

```
library(data.table);

select1 <- function (dt, range)  dt[, range, with=F]
select2 <- function (dt, range)  dt[, ..range]
select3 <- function (dt, range)  dt[, .SD, .SDcols=range] 

dt <- ggplot2::diamonds

range <- 1:3 # or 
range <- dt %>% names %>% .[1:3]

dt %>% select1(range);
dt %>% select2(range); 
dt %>% select3(range); 

dt %>% select1(-range);
dt %>% select2(-range); 
dt %>% select3(-range); # DOES NOT WORK

Also we note that this
dt %>% .[, ..(names(dt)[1:3])] # DOES NOT WORK
```

Therefore the best (most universal and fast) way to select multiple columns in `data.table` is the following:

```
# columns are selected using column numbers:
range <- 1:3
dt %>% select1(range); 
dt %>% .[, range, with=F]

# The same works if columns are selected using column names:
range <- names(dt) [1:3]
dt %>% select1(range); 
dt %>% .[, range, with=F]
```

PS.
If, instead of selecting multiple columns, you want to efficiently delete multiple columns from data.table by reference (i.e. instead of copying the entire data.table), then you can use data.table's `:=` operator. But I don't know how to do it for multiple columns in one line