# R data.table struggling with conditional subsetting when column name is predefined elsewhere

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Let's say I have a data table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=c(1,1,0,0),y=c(0,1,2,3))
column_name <- "x"

   x y
1: 1 0
2: 1 1
3: 0 2
4: 0 3
```

And I want to access all the rows where x = 1, but by using column_name.

The desired output should behave like this:

```
DT[x==1,]
   x y
1: 1 0
2: 1 1
```

but with `x` replaced by `column_name` in the input.

**Note that this problem is similar to but not quite the same as [Select subset of columns in data.table R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094645/select-subset-of-columns-in-data-table-r), and the solution there (using with=FALSE) doesn't work here.**

Here are all the things I've tried. None of them work.

```
DT[column_name ==1,]
DT[.column_name ==1,]
DT[.(column_name) ==1,]
DT[..column_name ==1,]
DT[."column_name" ==1,]
DT[,column_name ==1,]
DT[,column_name ==1,with=TRUE]
DT[,column_name ==1,with=FALSE]
DT[,.column_name ==1,with=TRUE]
DT[,.column_name ==1,with=FALSE]
DT[,..column_name ==1,with=TRUE]
DT[,..column_name ==1,with=FALSE]
DT[,."column_name" ==1,with=TRUE]
DT[,.column_name ==1,with=FALSE]
DT[column_name ==1,with=TRUE]
DT[column_name ==1,with=FALSE]
DT[[column_name==1,]]
subset(DT,column_name==1)
```

I also have `options(datatable.WhenJisSymbolThenCallingScope=TRUE)` enabled

There's obviously some kind of lexical trick I'm missing. I've spent several hours looking through vignettes and SO questions to no avail.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Assigning/Referencing a column name in data.table dynamically (in i, j and by)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818053/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can imagine this was very frustrating for you. I applaud the number of things you tried before posting. Here's one approach:

```
DT[get(column_name) == 1,]
   x y
1: 1 0
2: 1 1
```

If you need to use `column_name` in `J`, you can use `get(..column_name)`:

```
DT[,get(..column_name)]
[1] 1 1 0 0
```

The `..` instructs evaluation to occur in the parent environment.

Another approach for using a string in either `I` or `J` is with `eval(as.name(column_name))`:

```
DT[eval(as.name(column_name)) == 1]
   x y
1: 1 0
2: 1 1

DT[,eval(as.name(column_name))]
[1] 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: While I was trying several different attempts (including the `..` notation but in `i` not `j`), I know this works well-enough but find its necessity somewhat frustrating.

Comment: I've never been fond of `eval` solutions, though I understand they can bring value in otherwise difficult situations. I'm just waiting to see if R-injection is ever a concern, and [*Little `R`obbie Tables*](https://xkcd.com/327/) is the next thing (though `eval(parse(...))` is the real concern there).

Comment: Thanks!  I had so many tries before posting on SO, because, like I suspect many others find, it can be a bit daunting and you feel like you need to have an airtight question. The `get` function is weird. I feel like it somehow oughtn't to exist. In 3 years of R I haven't come across it before.

Comment: Or with `DT[DT[, ..column_name][[1]]==1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can subset the column by name and then select rows.

```
library(data.table)
DT[DT[[column_name]] == 1]

#   x y
#1: 1 0
#2: 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A little caveat, using `get()` directly with `paste0()` doesn't work. You have to assign the paste to a variable first, like:

```
# Doesn't work:
dt[get(paste0(column_name, 'some_string')) == 1]

# Does work:
this_col_name = paste0(column_name, 'some_string')
dt[get(this_col_name) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional answer I just discovered:
If there are multiple columns named this way and you want to return all of them, don't use `get`, use `mget`.

Example:

```
df <- data.table(x=1:4,y=1:4,z=1:4,w=1:4)    # here's my data table
desired_columns <- c("y","z","w")            # I want to return only columns Y, Z and W
```

if I try:

```
> df[,get(desired_columns)]
Error in get(desired_columns) : first argument has length > 1
```

Instead:

```
> df[,mget(desired_columns)]
   y z w
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 2 2
3: 3 3 3
4: 4 4 4
```