# Select matching columns from a data table using a list of column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 55993 rows and 2923 columns, a subset looks like this:

```
            Name Description GTEX-N7MS-0007-SM-2D7W1 GTEX-N7MS-0008-SM-4E3JI GTEX-N7MS-0011-R10A-SM-2HMJK
 ENSG00000223972     DDX11L1                       0                       0                            0
 ENSG00000227232      WASH7P                     158                     166                          209
 ENSG00000243485  MIR1302-11                       0                       0                            4
 ENSG00000237613     FAM138A                       0                       0                            0
 ENSG00000268020      OR4G4P                       0                       0                            0
 ENSG00000240361     OR4G11P                       0                       0                            0
```

The Name column is unique so it can be used as the key:

```
setkey(dat,Name)
```

I have a list of 175 columns which I want to extract, for e.g. like this:

```
col.list <- c('GTEX-N7MS-0011-R10A-SM-2HMJK','GTEX-N7MS-0008-SM-4E3JI','GTEX-N7MS-0826-SM-2AXU2')
```

However, it is possible that the table does contain all the columns.

How do I extract all the rows from data.table, with all the existing columns which match those in col.list? I was thinking something on the lines of:

```
dat[,.(col.list)]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `dat[, col.list, with=FALSE]`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you move this to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Also similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/11940605/1191259 & http://stackoverflow.com/q/15007979/1191259

Comment: If your vector has names that aren't colnames, drop 'em by taking the intersection, `dat[, intersect(names(dat), col.list), with=FALSE]` Generally, not cool to change your question after you have an answer.

Comment: I did not know that the answer would throw an error until I tried it on the full dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dat[, ..col.list]` .

The `..` signals to `data.table` to look in the parent frame (i.e. the environment where `dat` is located) rather than within `dat` itself.

Comment: There are some columns that it cannot find and is throwing an error.

Comment: Maybe those columns include some symbols that break the code? If that's the case you can think of changing the names somehow before creating the dataset, or have a process that changes the column names after the dataset creation.

Comment: I have edited my question, the col.list has a new column name that is not present, and it throws an error. There is no special character in that.

Comment: I used your and Frank's suggestion and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I helped. Good that @Frank spotted the duplicate. You might find some more info in the answers there for future reference.