# loop over maximum values of each column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've got the following problem.

I want to build a vector with the maximum values for each column of my data.table - but it didn't work and the ouput vector was just the index sequence of my for loop.

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100, 1, 100), ncol = 10))  # Example dataframe
setDT(d) # to create a data.table

max_values <- numeric(length = ncol(d))

# Loop through each column
for (i in 1:ncol(d)) {
  max_values[i] <- max(d[, c(i)])
}
```

So my max_values vector consists of the numbers 1:10, but not the maximum values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ```apply(d, 2, max)```

Comment: To solve my problem yes, I just don't understand why the for loop doesn't work with a data.table.

Comment: If this were a `data.frame(.)` then it would work, but since it's `data.table`, the integer-reference in `j=` doesn't work the same: it's a _calculation_, so non-standard evaluation works (i.e., symbols not strings, so `d[, V1]` works, `d[, "V1"]` does not do what one might expect), and expressions in `j=` are _evaluated_, not column-referenced. In this case `c(i)` is just evaluated as the value of `i`. A roundabout way to do it is to learn that `.SDcols` _can_ do integer referencing, ala `max(d[, .SD,, .SDcols=i])`

Comment: This question is about data.table whereas the purported duplicate is about a data.frame.i I have reopened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380628/why-does-work-to-pass-column-names-in-a-character-vector-variable) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940605/selecting-a-subset-of-columns-in-a-data-table) for an explanation of why `c(i)` doesn't work.

A couple ways to get the `for` loop to work:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(d)) max_values[i] <- max(d[, ..i])
for (i in 1:ncol(d)) max_values[i] <- max(d[[i]])
```

Or we could do:

```
max_values <- d[, sapply(.SD, max)]
```

Or even:

```
max_values <- Rfast::colMaxs(as.matrix(d), TRUE)
```

Which to use depends on the size and shape of `d` (and available memory). For example:

```
library(Rfast)
library(bench)

x <- runif(1e6)

lapply(
  lapply(1:5, \(i) as.data.table(matrix(x, 10^i))),
  \(dt) mark(
    {y <- numeric(ncol(dt)); for (i in 1:ncol(dt)) y[i] <- max(dt[[i]]); y},
    unname(dt[,sapply(.SD, max)]),
    colMaxs(as.matrix(dt), TRUE)
  )
)
```

Results in:

```
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 { y <- nu… 645.2ms 645.2ms    1.55     783.5KB   12.4       1     8    645.2ms
#> 2 unname(dt…   22.8s   22.8s    0.0439    29.1MB    0.570     1    13      22.8s
#> 3 colMaxs(a… 548.2ms 548.2ms    1.82      10.8MB   10.9       1     6    548.2ms
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 { y <- nu…  53.7ms  63.1ms     16.1    78.17KB    14.4      9     8      557ms
#> 2 unname(dt… 328.5ms 334.1ms      2.99    2.81MB     4.49     2     3      668ms
#> 3 colMaxs(a…  45.5ms  59.1ms     17.2     7.94MB     9.58     9     5      522ms
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 { y <- nu…   5.1ms  5.51ms     163.     7.86KB     18.4    62     7      380ms
#> 2 unname(dt… 12.97ms 13.97ms      71.7  327.49KB     10.6    27     4      377ms
#> 3 colMaxs(a…  7.42ms  8.39ms     102.     7.66MB     18.3    39     7      383ms
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 { y <- nume… 1.33ms 2.18ms      464.      848B     4.33   214     2      462ms
#> 2 unname(dt[,… 2.14ms 3.44ms      283.   77.57KB     4.28   132     2      467ms
#> 3 colMaxs(as.… 4.83ms 5.33ms      186.    7.63MB    30.9     60    10      323ms
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 { y <- nu…  948.4µs 1.59ms      615.        0B     0      308     0      501ms
#> 2 unname(dt…   1.42ms 2.07ms      483.   49.02KB     2.06   235     1      486ms
#> 3 colMaxs(a…   3.38ms 4.35ms      228.    7.63MB    36.4     69    11      302ms
```

And one more:

```
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(runif(1e7), 1e6))
bench::mark(
  {y <- numeric(ncol(dt)); for (i in 1:ncol(dt)) y[i] <- max(dt[[i]]); y},
  unname(dt[,sapply(.SD, max)]),
  colMaxs(as.matrix(dt), TRUE)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression                             min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                          <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 { y <- numeric(ncol(dt)) for (i in… 11.8ms   13ms      76.0   56.23KB     2.05
#> 2 unname(dt[, sapply(.SD, max)])      10.2ms 11.2ms      88.5    1.64MB     2.01
#> 3 colMaxs(as.matrix(dt), TRUE)        34.2ms 34.9ms      28.3    76.4MB    39.6
```

Comment: `as.matrix` copies the (potentially very large) data.table, which is inefficient. The canonical approach with a data.table is `d[, sapply(.SD, max)]`.

Comment: Using `with=FALSE` as in `for (i in seq_along(d)) max_values[i] <- max(d[, i, with = FALSE])` also works.

Comment: @jblood94 I expect if you try 1e6 rows and 10 columns, it will start to be the fastest solution.

Comment: But the normal d[,c(n)] with n being any column number works well...